# React Native 0.26 No suitable image URL loader found when displaying image from asset-library

Tags: ios, image, reactjs, react-native

I recently updated my project to 0.26. After fixing to breaking changes and what not, I get an error when I´m trying to display an image from the asset-library using the react-native-camera module and saving to camera roll. Currently only tested on iOS.

```
    [error][tid:com.facebook.react.ImageLoaderURLCacheQueue]
    [RCTImageLoader.m:332] No suitable image URL loader found for
    assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=DC49E90A-8F0D-41E8-9120-  1A7517735C44&ext=JPG
```

All I´m doing is using this asset URL in my Image component like:

`resizeMode="contain" source={{uri: props.imageUri}}`

Answer (score 5):

If someone else is experiencing this. RTCCameraRoll is now optional and has to be added manually to the project and Build Phases. Doing this solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Get the RCTCameraRoll project from node_modules/react-native and move it to xCode project. Then add the library in the build phases => link binaries.

Comment: official doc [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html) to link RCTCameraRoll